# Laravel mysql data input.. Check if Users follow each other

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

```html
public function follow(Request $request){

        $response = array();
        $response['code'] = 400;

        $following_user_id = $request->input('following');
        $follower_user_id = $request->input('follower');
        $element = $request->input('element');
        $size = $request->input('size');

        $following = User::find($following_user_id);
        $follower = User::find($follower_user_id);

        if ($following && $follower && ($following_user_id == Auth::id() || $follower_user_id == Auth::id())){

            $relation = UserFollowing::where('following_user_id', $following_user_id)->where('follower_user_id', $follower_user_id)->get()->first();

            if ($relation){
                if ($relation->delete()){
                    $response['code'] = 200;
                    if ($following->isPrivate()) {
                        $response['refresh'] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $relation = new UserFollowing();
                $relation->following_user_id = $following_user_id;
                $relation->follower_user_id = $follower_user_id;
                if ($following->isPrivate()){
                    $relation->allow = 0;
                }else{
                    $relation->allow = 1;
                }
                if ($relation->save()){
                    $response['code'] = 200;
                    $response['refresh'] = 0;

                    if ($following && $follower){

                        $relationz = new UserRelationship();
                        $relationz->main_user_id = $following_user_id;
                        $relationz->relation_type = 1;
                        $relationz->related_user_id = $follower_user_id;
                        $relationz->allow = 1;
                        $relationz->save();

                    }                    
                }
            }

            if ($response['code'] == 200){
                $response['button'] = sHelper::followButton($following_user_id, $follower_user_id, $element, $size);
            }
        }

        return Response::json($response);

    }
```

Hey guys, I have this code which creates a follow among two users.
I added a function to be personal friends 'relationz' as well.
Currently when you follow a user, you become 'relationz' automatically..
I would like to create a new 'relationz' only when the follower is also followed by the same person, my question is what change must I make here to either:
a) stop an auto-friend when only one user follows..
b) detect when each person follows each other..
I'm not sure which is the better logic?

I was wrongly thinking the simple "if (follower && following)" was enough, maybe it is just in the wrong place?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

How is your relations set up?

since i see a whole lot of code and if the follow function is in you controller, that will be a mess to sort out later when bug fixing.

so you have a many to many relation ship called followers in the user model?

so if user a would follow user b user a would give a follower result of 1

and if user b would have followers than it would be 0 correct?

so what i would do, if both are following each other you should have 2 rows with both users in the pivot table.

so I would create a new relationship relationz with a wherehas query in it

```php
public function relationz {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Follower::class)->whereHas('followers' , function($query) {
        $query->where('followed_id', auth()->user_id);
    })
}
```

Something like that.